# Android BLE not reading/writing nothing sometimes, restarts working after using a third-party app

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop an android app to connect to a BLE device. The app works fine, but sometimes (maybe becouse of a connection fail) every "onDescriptorRead", "onDescriptorWrite", "onCharacteristicWrite", etc. have status: 1 and nothing works.

When this happens, nothing solves the problem, i've tried restarting bluetooh on my phone, restarting the phone and restarting the BLE device. After a lot of tryes i found something that solve the problem:

Using this third-party app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner

I close my app, than I open the BLE Scanner app and through it I disconnect and reconnect my device. Then if I return to my app, everything returns to work as aspected.

The question is: what is this app doing to my phone (maybe a particular method to disconnect the BLE device) that is restoring a working connection?

Comment: Is your app able to scan some devices?

Comment: Yes, the scan process never fails

Comment: But not found another device that is used your app. right?

Comment: My app finds my BLE device correctly, the problem is with every write/read methods

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/Aspsine/BlueChat

Comment: Another things have you added location permission and enable location in your app?

Comment: Not sure it contains a solution to my problem...

Comment: Yes of course, and sometimes the app works perfectly... I think the problem is something related to some sort of bluetooth cache...

Comment: Maybe you can post some of your code, especially how you execute the GATT operations and how you handle the callbacks.